# An elementary proof that cos(x) in the required condition takes only 5 rational values

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, trigonometry

Assume that $x$ is a rational multiple of $π$ such is $\cos(x)$ is also rational. Then the number of values of $\cos(x)$ under the conditions is?

I did read niven's proof of this, but it uses complex numbers extensively and I am not that much well equipped with complex number knowledge to understand that, that's why I am looking for an elementary proof.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think Niven's proof does not use complex analysis. The proof can be written in a manner which avoids the symbol $i$.

Comment: It would be nice if you can study Niven's proof and ask about the part where you are facing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

This can be proven with two ingredients:

- the Chebyshev 's polynomials,
- the rational root theorem.

Let $x=\dfrac pq\pi$, then $qx$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ and $\cos(qx)=\pm1$. But $\cos(qx)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\cos x$ (you can prove this by the addition formula). Now given the values of the extreme coefficients, $P_q(\cos x)=0$ cannot have a rational root in the range $[-1,1]$ except for very few cases.